# How to configure print layout from website with background on multiple pages?

Tags: css

I'm trying to print from my website to PDF. I have a background image and want a 1 in margin. When printing, the background only gets added to the first page and the top margin only applies to the first page and the bottom margin only applies to the last page.

I need to print pages that can then be placed in a booklet.

Using just a color instead of an image does place the color on every page, though stops when the text ends without covering the bottom of the page.

I have tried various background-size and @page styles

```
<head>
<style>
body {
    background-image: url("../includes/images/paperback.jpg");
    margin: 1in;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
test<br><br> <!-- repeated to fill multiple pages -->
</body>
```

Comment: You might have some luck with breaking your content for printing specifically using [break-inside](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-inside).

Answer (score 0):

I just received my answer elsewhere. I had been trying to use Chrome for this, but was directed to work in Firefox. By adding the same background to every div, setting the div margin to 0, and letting Firefox add a 1in margin, I was able to get a file that I can then add a background to in Acrobat that then fills in the empty margins. It works, though I welcome a simpler answer.